# Laravel Eloquent created_at is getting updated

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I just hit a snag with Eloquent's (Laravel 5.2.10) default timestamps. By default the `$table->timestamps()` method gives you a `created_at` and an `updated_at` column in your table which are updated accordingly.

However, when I was trying some test entries, I noticed that when you update a record, the `updated_at` field gets updated, as it should, but the `created_at` field **also** gets updated: its hours stays at the created time, but the minutes and seconds get updated to match the `updated_at` field.

If that was too wordy, here is an example:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
| created_at          | updated_at          |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2016-01-13 17:13:27 | 2016-01-13 22:13:27 |
| 2016-01-13 16:14:41 | 2016-01-13 21:14:41 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Notice that the minutes and seconds are the exact same for the `created_at` and `updated_at` field.

I tried to look through the `Model` class where the timestamps are set, but it turns out the `setCreatedAt()` method is indeed not called when just updating a record.

**Why** does this happen?
**How** do I prevent the `created_at` field from changing? (more important)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is probably related to this issue here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/11518

Long story short, many people's `created_at` column had the `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` attribute.

As stated on the Github page:

> MySQL 5.7 no longer allows 0000-00-00 as a valid timestamp with
>   strict mode turned on (which it is by default). So either use
>   `->nullableTimestamps()` or `->timestamp()->useCurrent()`.

So, you can fix this by changing this:

```
$table->timestamps();
```

To either one of these options:

```
// Option 1:
$table->nullableTimestamps();

// Option 2:
$table->timestamp('updated_at')->useCurrent();
$table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
```

Also, on this MySQL page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html

> Alternatively, if `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp` is disabled (the default), do either of the following:
>
> Define the column with a DEFAULT clause that specifies a constant default value.
>
> Specify the NULL attribute. This also causes the column to permit NULL values, which means that you cannot assign the current timestamp by setting the column to NULL. Assigning NULL sets the column to NULL.

Comment: I ran a `composer update` which brought me up to 5.2.10, but the `timestamps()` method was still not working properly. However, the `nullableTimestamps()` does work just fine so I will use that for now (The issue you pointed me to seemed to indicate that this would become default `timestamps()` behavior, but for now it still doesn't work for me. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @tam Sorry about that. As of 5 hours ago (Laravel 5.2.9+), the changes have been reverted so `useCurrent()` is not the default behavior. It caused some issues with people who are using an older version of MySQL.

Comment: no problem. Thanks for the alternative and explanations